# Object reference not set to an instance of an object in instance of mapView

Tags: c#, wpf, esri, arcgis-runtime

I initialize this as `_mapView = Globals.AppMainMapView;` at constructor

Error occurred here when I use _mapView :

```
if (_mapView.Editor.Cancel.CanExecute(null))
{
    _mapView.Editor.Cancel.Execute(null);
}
```

Comment: which means `_mapView` is `null` at the time you tried to access it. [take a Look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: or _mapView.Editor, or _mapView.Editor.Cancel, or the method CanExecute tries to us a property or method of the object you pass (which is null)